# Kint and Codeigniter MAMP vs LAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter, mamp, lamp

I'm currently developing a site on my mac using MAMP. I recently included the kint library and everything seems to be working fine.

The other day I copied the files over to my linux machine and the site is working fine, however, I get the message `Unable to load the requested class: kint` whenever I get to a page where kint has been loaded - this does not happen with on my mac and I haven't changed any other files.

So far I've tried loading`'Kint/kint'` (as one thred suggested) and I've also tried autoloading the file, but neither work, meanwhile everything is still fine on my mac???

If anyone could shed some light on this, thank you!

Comment: try saving all files for desired OS (via notepad++) or in linux "convert" files via bash script. I assume there is problem with line breaks.

Comment: permission issue.  temporarily chmod the file to 0777 in your terminal and see if it now works.  If that is the case, you need to chown the website to _www or add _www to your wheel group, or whatever level you feel comfortable security-wise

Comment: @Kevin Florida isnt that weird that other libs/classes would load?

Comment: The `case` matters on a linux system. Make sure the filenames are in smallcaps, and the classname starts off with a Capital case when defining the class, and when you call it, call with small case.

Comment: The simplest way to use the `Kint` as I prefer to use is, place it outside the working folder, suppose your working folder was `home/www/mysite`, then place the kint folder in `home/www/`, and then while the project is in development stage, place `include "../kint/Kint.class.php";` inside in `index.php`, then you'll be able to access it anywhere. Then once it goes to production, you just need to remove that from `index.php`.

Comment: Thank you, everyone; especially @ISuthanBala. I had to type it as 'Kint/kint' (capitalising the first one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @IsuthanBala.

The answer was to use the format 'Directory/Class' but making sure that the capitalisation was accurate as well (something I had not initially checked).

e.g.

`$this->load->library('Kint/kint');`